# Disable all SQL Agent Jobs in a particular category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I have the following query that generates the commands necessary for me to disable all the SQL Agent jobs particular to a category.

```
Select 'Exec MSDB.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name = N''' + SJ.Name + ''', @Enabled = 0'
  FROM msdb..sysjobs SJ inner join msdb..syscategories SC
    on SJ.category_id = SC.category_id
 Where SJ.[Enabled] = 1
   and SC.Name = 'BI ETLs'
```

How can I automate this totally, so it will generate the commands and execute them without it being a manual process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = STUFF((    
  SELECT ';' + 'Exec MSDB.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name = N''' 
           + SJ.Name + ''', @Enabled = 0'
  FROM msdb..sysjobs SJ JOIN msdb..syscategories SC
    ON SJ.category_id = SC.category_id
 WHERE SJ.[Enabled] = 1
   and SC.Name = 'BI ETLs' FOR XML PATH('')),1 ,1, '') ;

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

With `SQL Server 2017`  it is much easier to concatenate strings using `STRING_AGG`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = (Select STRING_AGG('Exec MSDB.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name = N''' + SJ.Name + ''', @Enabled = 0', ';')
  FROM msdb..sysjobs SJ inner join msdb..syscategories SC
    on SJ.category_id = SC.category_id
 Where SJ.[Enabled] = 1
   and SC.Name = 'BI ETLs');

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
```